# Wiring for a new honeywell thermostat

Tags: thermostat

I am trying to install a basic Honeywell Programmable thermostat, but the wiring is a bit different, and I am reluctant to start taking it apart. I have a Goodman heat pump, which is occasionally blowing heat when it is set to cool. It seems to be happening more often, and I am hoping that a new thermostat might fix the problem. I am including pictures of how it was wired, as well as the new wiring plate. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Only one picture came thru....

Comment: Why do you think it's the thermostat's fault that the system is operating in the wrong direction?

Comment: The change over valve on the heat pump may be about to fail. That would explain why it doesn't cool sometimes.

Comment: After spending an hour and a half on hold, I found out from Honeywell that I bought a thermostat that is not compatible with my heat pump. I am hoping the problem is the thermostat, because it is the cheapest thing to fix. The research I have done has indicated that it is one of the possible culprits. I can't find much on my exact situation, though. Most people have the problem constantly. The fact that my problem is intermittent makes it a bit confusing.